# Why does $_SESSION only work when I am logged in?

Tags: php, session

I am including a pure PHP library (nothing to do with WordPress) into a few of my page templates. This library calls PHP session_start() function and references the $_SESSION["cart"] global variable. Because of the session_start I include the library at the top of my template.

When I am logged in the library functions exactly as it is supposed to, but when I log out, the $_SESSION variables appear not to store data. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: do you have debugging enabled?

Comment: if you are talking about ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); I am not.

Comment: I suggest [enabling debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see if there's a warning or error being generated that may give some indication as to why the session isn't starting.

Comment: "This library calls PHP session_start() ..." -- where/how is this library loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress doesn't use PHP sessions, so WordPress itself can not be related with your sessions working or not regarding if you are logged in or not (I think).

Try to call `session_start()` on `init` action instead of doing it in a template file and be sure it is called before your custom library is loaded. Also, it can be interesting to end the PHP session on user log in and user log out to start a fresh one:

```
add_action('init', 'cyb_start_session', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'cyb_end_session');
add_action('wp_login', 'cyb_end_session');

function cyb_start_session() {
    if( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
        // now you can load your library that use $_SESSION
    }
}

function cyb_end_session() {
    session_destroy();
}
```

Because you library calls `session_start()`, con avoid to call it yourself but you still needs to load your library on `init` and destroy sessions on log in/log out:

```
add_action('init', 'cyb_start_session', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'cyb_end_session');
add_action('wp_login', 'cyb_end_session');

function cyb_start_session() {
      // load your libreary here (assuming it calls session_start())
}

function cyb_end_session() {
    session_destroy();
}
```

The key is to start PHP sessions as earlier as possible, before output anything. On `init` with priority 1 is the earliest it can be done in WP enviroment. If you do before, session can be destroyed by [wp_unregister_GLOBALS()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unregister_GLOBALS).

A basic and silly but working example:

```
add_action('init', 'cyb_start_session', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'cyb_end_session');
add_action('wp_login', 'cyb_end_session');

function cyb_start_session() {
    if( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
        // now you can use $_SESSION
        $_SESSION['test'] = "test";
    }
}

function cyb_end_session() {
    session_destroy();
}


// This will print array(1) { ["test"]=> string(4) "test" }
// above the content of any post
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {

        var_dump($_SESSION);

        return $content;

} );
```

Comment: So, apparently the session isn't getting started inside cyb_start_session function. I test with if (!session_id())echo "session not created", and the template page shows "session not created".

Comment: How do I test to see if cyb_start_session is being called?

Comment: Have you ever tried my code as it is? I use it every time I need to use PHP sessions within WordPress and it works perfectly. As I say in the answer, be sure to call `session_start()` on `init` and use PHP sessions on later events.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "to a T".

Comment: I am following it exactly... I think that the root of the problem has got to do with the fact that it works when I am signed in, and not when I am signed out.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add code/explanation of how are you loading your library? I've added an example in the question that show how it works. Copy and paste that exact code and you will see it.

Answer (score 2):

I have been thinking about using Wordpress' meta keys as session variables. Something like this:

```
add_user_meta(
    int $user_id,
    string $meta_key,
    mixed $meta_value,
    bool $unique = false
);
```

Wordpress will keep the meta values, link them to a user, and you can delete those values later on.